IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible when working with googlesheet from drive
I'm trying to write a dataframe into a googlesheet on google drive using python and I keep getting the same error : "IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible".
So here's how my code works :
My file contains three (3) sheets. I'm interested in working on "Data" :

I read the file using : df_cases = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Data')

I execute the different functions of my main code on the dataframe

I try to save back the new df_cases to the same sheet using the code :


from openpyxl import Workbook
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    # Load the existing workbook
    writer.book = load_workbook(file_path)

    # Write the df_cases DataFrame to the "Data" sheet
    df_cases.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', index=False)

But, I get the same error over and over : IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible
PS1 : I'm using google colab
PS2 : I have a part of my code that asks me for access to the drive and all, eventhough I don't think that's the problem!.
PS3 : Deleting the whole sheet and rewriting it with the same name is an option, but I need to keep the other 2 sheets
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Try with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') and remove writer.book = load_workbook(file_path).
